# SOAP Request Error using Strong Soap npm package with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl, strong-soap

When I try with soap ui or axios everything is working fine but I try to make a request using strong-soap I got the following error.

```
 try {
  let url = 'http://10.254.173.170:7800/GetInfoFin/GetInfoFin?wsdl';
  let args = { "Username": "CRM", "Password": "123", "IP": "127.0.0.0","ServiceIdentifierType": "PSTN", "ServiceIdentifier": "0512300858", };
 soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
   console.log(client.describe())
   client.GetInfoFinHttpService.GetInfoFinHttpPort.GetInfoFin(args, function (err, result) {
     res.send(err)
   });
 });
 } catch (error) {
 }
```

Comment: I am getting the following error response from above code

Comment: I am getting 500 internal server error.